# Is there a way to enable SQL logging programmaticaly in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In symfony2 is there a way to enable SQL logging programmaticaly, I mean, change the doctrine:dbal:logging item in config.yml at runtime ?

Comment: Is [this](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/) what you mean?

Comment: well actually no. I asked for a way to programmatically change the setting in config.yml. But I didn't knew this functionality. Very interesting and in the end I can do what I want. So if you want put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, solution is described at http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/